# Prove $f'(x_n) \to f'(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f: I \to R $ differentiable and $x \in I$.
Prove that there exists a sequence {$x_n$} in $I$ different from $x$ such that $f'(x_n) \to f'(x)$

So below is my approach to this problem:
Take an arbitrary sequence {$y_n$} and apply the MVT, we have there exists a sequence {$x_n$}  between {$y_n$} and $x$ such that
$\frac{f(y_n) - f(x)}{y_n - x} = f'(x_n)$
Then taking $\lim_{y_n\to x}$ and since $y_n$ is arbitrary, we have the desired result.

Am I correct here? Thank you!

Comment: does taking a sequence $y_n$ different from x for all n resolve this problem?

Comment: Btw: I noticed that you got answers for many of your questions, but never *accepted* an answer so far. If you are not aware of it: Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/196432) for more information.

Comment: Oh, thank you for letting me know. Yes, I was not aware of this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but you should emphasize that $y_n \ne x$ and consequently $x_n \ne x$. I would formulate it as follows:

Choose any sequence $(y_n)$ in $I$ such that $y_n \to x$ and $y_n \ne x$ for all $n$. The [mean-value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), applied to the interval $[x, y_n]$ or $[y_n, x]$, states that there is an $x_n$ *strictly between* $x$ and $y_n$ such that
$$
\frac{f(y_n) - f(x)}{y_n - x} = f'(x_n) \, .
$$
Then $x_n \to x$, $x_n \ne x$, and
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} f'(x_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(y_n) - f(x)}{y_n - x} = f'(x) \, .
$$